# Symfony - clone all values from one object onto another by ID?

Tags: php, api, symfony

I am stuck in a huge mess.

I am trying to write a method that should receive user_id and check if there is a profile change request attached to that user.

If there is (has field change_request set to true in users table), the change request should be applied -> all user data fields from change request table by that id should be moved to that user table.

My service

```
public function getUserApplyChangeRequest($id)
{
    $a =$this->getUserRepository()->find($id);
    $b =$this->getChangeProfileRequestRepository()->find($id);

    $b = clone $a;

    $this->em->persist($b);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

My controller..

```
public function userApplyChangeRequestAction($changeRequest)
{

    $this->requirePostParams(['user_id']);

    if ($changeRequest === 1){
    $applyChange = $this->get('user')->getUserApplyChangeRequest($this->getUser());
    }

    return $this->success();
}
```

I need help because I am stuck and don't really know what to do wtih this lines of code but I putted an example of what I want to happen.

Comment: How complex is the "change request" how many properties are in it ? With  $b = clone $a; you are just overwriting the object you got from getChangeProfileRequestRepository with a.

Comment: I need to clone 5 indentical fields from changeprofilerequest table to user table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to set the properties yourself if there are only five:

```
public function getUserApplyChangeRequest($id)
{
    $a =$this->getUserRepository()->find($id);
    $b =$this->getChangeProfileRequestRepository()->find($id);

    $a->setPropertyOne($b->getPropertyOne());
    $a->setPropertyTwp($b->getPropertyTwo());

    $this->em->persist($a);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Other option is to get all the properties of your Change Object with doctrine and call the getters/setters that way (untested, make sure to add NULL checks and skip the ID field):

```
$props = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($b))->getColumnNames();
foreach($props as $prop){
    //get value from B
    $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(get_class($b),'get'.ucfirst($prop));
    $value = $reflectionMethod->invoke($b);

    //set value in A
    $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(get_class($a),'set'.ucfirst($prop));
    $reflectionMethod->invoke($a, $value);
}
```